# motor does not move without Serial.println

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, stepper

having strange behavior with motor shield and steppers. when i'm trying to make `onestep`, motor just makes some high-frequent noise, but when i add `Serial.println` for debugging, it moves as intended.

what is going on here?

here is an example:

```
#include AFMotor.h //dunno how to put angle brackets here

AF_Stepper lrM(48, 1);

void rightStep() {  
  lrM.onestep(BACKWARD, INTERLEAVE);
}
void leftStep() {  
  lrM.onestep(FORWARD, INTERLEAVE);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ready");
}

void loop() {
  rightStep();
//Serial.println("right");
}
```

Comment: We need [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok. i've added one, but it is very common usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `Serial.println` adds additional delay so stepper motor can react. Without it changes are way too fast (= high frequency noise) to do whole step.

Try to add `delay(1);` or more into the main loop.

Comment: i thought that if `onestep` function is blocking, it would be ok, but it appeared that i need delay(10) so that motor can run. thank you!

Comment: Method step contains delays, but there are no delays in onestep (at least not obvious ones).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Serial print statement running really quickly the output buffer will fill up and the `print` command will have to wait for there to be room; That causes the command to take a substantial amount of time to complete.

When the statement is missing, you loop probably runs a few hundred times faster than without it (depending on how long `onestep` takes), probably fast enough that the physical motor can not keep up.

Try adding a delay of a few milliseconds or some kind of rate limiting to the program and then see how much of a difference `serial.println` makes.